# How do I restore the actionbar when restoring activity with selected text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm writing an application where I not only want the text selection to be restored (which I have already implemented) when the app comes back from a stop, but I also want to restore the visible ActionBar items. That is, I want to restore the set of items representing the actions select all, cut, copy and paste, as well as the check that unselects text.

So, how do I make the unselect, select all, cut, copy and paste ActionBar items be visible when I come back to my activity if I was selecting text when I left it?